# Android - how to scale a view by a % of the display size?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-xml

I am working with Android studio and kotlin. My app has a `HorizontalScrollView`, which contains a `LinearLayout` with up to an infinite amount of `strip_view.xml` layouts (1 strip for each audio channel). My goal is to make each strip exactly 1/8th of `match_parent` wide so I can display exactly 8 strips at a time at all times while being able to scroll.

This is how the main layout and the strip layout currently look (to be expanded obviously but only the outer containers are relevant for this question).

[Main layout (ignore the error indicator it's just "no speakable text")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X15mK.png)

[Strip layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Enrf.png)

I have tried 2 approaches, both failed because for some reason the width of the parent View (the `LinearLayout`), which I scale with always remains 0, making the strips disappear entirely.

**NOTE**: I can't work with `RecyclerView` in this project, please don't suggest solutions related it.

**Approach 1: scale the views before inflating**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        val listOfStrips: List<Strip> = List(50) { Strip(it + 1) }
        val llScrollableContent = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.llScrollableContent)
        val stripWidth = llScrollableContent.width / 8


        for (strip in listOfStrips) {
            val stripLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.strip_view, llScrollableContent, false)
            val title: TextView = stripLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvStripTitle)
            val stripContainer: ConstraintLayout =
                stripLayout.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.clStripContainer)

            val layoutParams = stripContainer.layoutParams as LayoutParams
            layoutParams.width = stripWidth
            stripContainer.layoutParams = layoutParams


            title.text = strip.id.toString()
            llScrollableContent.addView(stripLayout)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Approach 2: Inflate the layout, then rescale the views.**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)

        val listOfStrips: List<Strip> = List(50) {Strip(it + 1) }
        val llScrollableContent = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.llScrollableContent)


        for(strip in listOfStrips){
            val stripLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.strip_view, llScrollableContent, false)
            val title: TextView = stripLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvStripTitle)
            val stripContainer: ConstraintLayout = stripLayout.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.clStripContainer)




            title.text = strip.id.toString()
            llScrollableContent.addView(stripLayout)
        }

        val stripWidth = llScrollableContent.width / 8
        for(i in 0 until llScrollableContent.childCount){
            val childView = llScrollableContent.getChildAt(i)
            val layoutParamsStrip = childView.layoutParams
            layoutParamsStrip.width = stripWidth
            childView.layoutParams = layoutParamsStrip
        }
    }
```

Edit: I additionally added the layout XML files

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clOuter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsvStripeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="310dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llScrollableContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

strip_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clStripContainer"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStripTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="default text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, First one will work for you. But try setting the width of `stripLayout` instead of  `stripContainer`. I hope it will work. If you need any further assistance kindly share your xmls as well

Comment: Hey @KamalSubhani thanks for the help. I adjusted so I scale the stripLayout instead of stripContainer and it still doesn't work (stripWidth still equals 0). I have now posted the XMLs, hope they can help somehow

Answer (score 0):

The issue why my approaches didn't work is because I didn't know that inflating the layout isn't equal to drawing the layout, meaning even after it gets inflated its elements' dimensions can still be == 0px.

Every time the dimensions of a UI element need to be measured (for example to dynamically scale a View as a % of a UI element) a Layout Listener must be used. I don't know all the types of Layout Listeners but the one I used is `OnGlobalLayoutListener` which is a callback function that gets called every time the UI gets updated anywhere.